# How to specify tenant in API request to Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, kibana-6, elk

I need to get all indices from Global tenant in Kibana 6.7.1:

`GET /api/saved_objects/_find?type=index-pattern`

How can I specify tenancy?

Comment: didn't get exactly what you need, but if you just want to get the details of all indices then see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.1/_list_all_indices.html

Comment: @AmitKhandelwal it doesn't exist on 6.7;

Comment: @AmitKhandelwal I need to get all indices, but in Global tenacy (apparently new thing in Elastic).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what plugin you are using for Kibana multi tenancy.

But if you are using SearchGuard Kibana security plugin, you can use the HTTP Header `curl -H 'securitytenant: privateTenant'`

If you are using opendistro Kibana security plugin, you can use the HTTP Header `curl -H 'sgtenant: privateTenant'`